# @BeanProperty causes "ambiguous reference" error, but does not appear to be ambiguous

Tags: scala

```
class Foo(@BeanProperty var bar:String) {

  def setBar(d:Double) {
    bar = d.toString
  }

}
```

This produces "error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method setBar in class Foo of type (x$1: String)Unit
and  method setBar in class Foo of type (d: Double)Unit
match expected type ?
class Foo(@BeanProperty var bar:String) {"

How can setBar(x:String) be ambiguous with setBar(d:Double)? Or is that not what the error message  is trying to convey?

Comment: Try marking the whole class with `@BeanInfo` instead of marking each member with `@BeanProperty`. Maybe that will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Please file an ticket on [issues.scala-lang.org](https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).